# Apply middleware conditionally based on auth in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to achieve the following:

Create a route with 2 groups of middleware. 1 applies when not logged in and the other applies when you are.

The auth middleware obviously catches this but I want to be able to reach the route without auth.

```
Route::get('my-route', ...)
  ->middleware('not-auth')
  ->middleware('when-authed') 
  ->name('my.route');
```

The route should be accessible when not logged in with NO other middleware applied
The route should have other middleware applied when logged in which will include auth:sanctum checks

I am happy to apply custom logic in the controller or the routes file

I have tried using the constructor in the controller but auth is not available to check if the user is logged in at time of instantiation.

As an example of something i have tried to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve, see below:

```
$authMiddleware = [
  'auth:sanctum',
  config('jetstream.auth_session'),
  'verified',
  'shared.ui'
];

Route::get('/route', [class::class, 'index'])
  ->middleware((auth()->check()) ? $authMiddleware : [])
  ->name('route');
```

Comment: u normally have this 2 middlewares: `guest` and `auth`. so for routes guest-only u use `Route::middleware('guest')->...`. For auth-only routes u use `Route::middleware('auth')->`

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of guest but I want to use this route for both guest and registered. I want to use specific middleware which will only apply when they are logged in but I don't want that middleware applied when they are guests

Comment: does this help: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#middleware-groups

Comment: if u want to make a route for authenticated users and for guest users, u can just NOT use the `guest` nor `auth` middlewares. so it's a route for everyone

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can simply remove that middleware and then, access to user inside controller. TO make this work, you need to add guard to auth function as well, which will be like ````auth()->guard("api")->user()````

Comment: I do not need to access the user, just their logged in state. I want the user to see the verified page if they are logged in but not force the user to login to view the page.

Comment: this makes no sense

Comment: I can't understand what you are going to do with that middleware if you don't need to have access to that user. In that case, just don't use any middleware.

Comment: I know it sounds odd. I am creating a page that shows data, click a button to proceed, you must login or register, after login or register, return to the page BUT user must verify email first so must only be shown verify when logged in

Comment: okay so a guest user is filling a form, and when is filled, u want them to log in and go back to the same form but the user has to validate their email and can only be shown if is verified. hmm... i think u should reconsider how u r doing this and change it

Answer (score 0):

Right, I have rewritten the verified middleware to resolve my issue and applied it as a different middleware on the route. This then resolves the issue I had where you had to be logged in with the middleware.

See below:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    //removed from start of if statement on original verify middlware !$request->user() ||
    if (($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
            : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Added alias to route middleware

```
    'auth.verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerifiedWhenLoggedIn::class,
```

Applied `auth.verified` on the route in question

Thank you to ericmp for suggesting I should be looking at doing this a different way and thanks to the rest of you for your comments.